# What does "Activity Time" mean?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get Google Analytics Reporting API on Json.
I got the data correctly but cannot understand the meaning of the columns.

What does "Activity Time" mean?
Is it the time user access the webpage?

Comment: plase edit your question and include your code.   What exactly do you mean by active time what column is this returning in and what dimensions and metrics are you requesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity is the number of minutes that you have been active throughout the day.

Active users are those who have sent a hit to Analytics within the last five minutes. Active users per page is the number of users who have sent their most recent hit from that page.

It also shows the referrals for active users and the pages through which these users entered your site and their geographic locations.

Ways to use Real-Time
With Real-Time, you can immediately and continuously monitor the effects that new campaigns and site changes have on your traffic. Here are a few of the ways you might use Real-Time:

monitor whether new and changed content on your site is being viewed
understand usage of your mobile app through event tracking
see whether a one-day promotion is driving traffic to your site or app, and which pages these users are viewing
monitor the immediate effects on traffic from a blog/social network post or tweet
verify that the tracking code is working on your site or app
monitor goal completions as you test changes to your site